# Bootstrap grid system not showing the correct column division

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hello, to cut story short, in the bar above " AllDay Market Employees" is a div col md 12, below it each div is a col md 6, on the left photo (the blue shirt) the div is all fine, on the second div ( the yellow shirt) you can see there is a lot of blank space next to it, is this related to padding and margin or what?

```
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="product-item">
                           <a href="#"><img src="'.$img.'" height="370px" width="270px" alt="">
                           <div class="down-content">
                            <center><strong>'.$firstname.' &nbsp '.$lastname.'</strong><small>('.$ID.')</small></center>
                             </div>
                              <br>
                              <div>
                              <ul>
                              <li><strong>PerHour:</strong>₪'.$perhour.'</li>
                              <li><strong>Residence:</strong>'.$residence.'</li>
                              <li><strong>PIN:</strong>'.$pin.'</li>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                        <a href="editEmployeeForm.php?id='.$ID.'">
                         <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" class="filled-button" class="editBtn">Edit</button>
                         </a>
                         <form action="updateEmployee.php" method="post">
                         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$ID.'">
                         <fieldset>
                         <button type="submit" name="employeeDel" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                         </fieldset>
                         </form>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: format your code. Maybe it will only solve your problem..seems like `a`, `ul` tags is not closed properly

Comment: I closed them and nothing happened :/

Comment: share full code along with col-12 and custom style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very inclear. Try to format your code. Here I give you some information. For creating bootstrap gird you have to create **row** div as a ***grid*** parent div. Like that-

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   ......
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   ......
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   ......
  </div>
</div>
```

As your code you give an image width. That's why you can understand if the grid contain full width. You can remove it give width 100%.

```
<img src="'.$img.'" height="370px" width="270px" alt="">
```

In your code somewhere you do not provide empty tag. Please complete it. And follow the bootstrap documentation.

Comment: I had a div "row" missing somewhere, it solved the problem thanks.